# How to get total in crystal report

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible to get the total of a column in crystal report?
if so i want to make total of a single column in the crystalreport.
could you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either you can make the crystal report by dynamic data sending to it or make a stored procedure which gives total of a column and get the result in crystal report by drag and drop.

Comment: Seriously? It's that difficult to get a total?  No wonder I never used Crystal Reports.